# olingo jpa processor v4 Exception when using @ManyToOne relation

Tags: spring-data-jpa, odata, olingo

olingo jpa processor v4 Exception when using @ManyToOne relation.

com.sap.olingo.jpa.metadata.core.edm.mapper.exception.ODataJPAModelException: Error when creating Referential Constraints for 'content': Property for 'content_id' not found at 'Repository'

```
@ManyToOne(optional = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "content_id",  insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Repository getContent() {
    return content;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "space_id",  insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Space getSpace() {
    return space;
}
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use refencedColumnName.
refencedColumnName is there to specify another column as the id column of the other table.

```
@ManyToOne(optional = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "content_id",referencedColumnName="here the id of repository",insertable = false, updatable= false)
```